# JavaFx - How to assign a TextField input to string or integer

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Hello guys what iam trying to do is get an input which is currently written in TextField. When button is clicked the text in TextField will be assigned to the string, so i can compare that string with some other string. (TextField is imported by scenebuilder). Thanks for every help.

What iam doing is not working:

```
@FXML
private TextField userInput;

private void whenClicked(ActionEvent event){
    String compareText = "Hello";
    String text = userInput.getText();
    if(compareText == text){
        System.out.println("Strings are same");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Strings are not same");
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem, exactly? And same procedure as with your last question (which you deleted, just to repost .. DON'T!!): [mcve] please, and stick to java naming conventions .. NOW!!

Comment: I want to get the text from TextField so i can camapre it to some string. I dont know how to explain it better.

Comment: work through a tutorial on how to use properties ... you want to listen to changes of the field's textProperty ..

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the problem with `TextField.getText()`, this is the proper way to get content from the FXML component.

However, never compare strings with the == operator; when used in objects like `String`, this operator compares **object adresses** but not their content.

Use `String.equals()` instead:

```
if(compareText.equals(text))
    System.out.println("Strings are same");
else
    System.out.println("Strings are not same");
```

Comment: Thanks program is now working properly. :}